# Which data type should I use to deal with time(hour and minute)?

Tags: iphone, ios

I want to create an alarm app in iPhone.

For example, I want to alarm at 8:40 every day or on some days of a week.
In SQL(database) or other programing language, there is a class or data type like `Time` to deal with hour and minute.
But I can't find a class like `NSTime` in iPhone.
Which class or data type should I use?
Should I use NSDate? or NSInteger?

**EDIT**
I want deal with hh:mm. 
I don't need date part(yyyy-mm-dd).

If I should use NSDate for hh:mm.
Which date(yyyy-mm-dd) should be set to the date variable?

Comment: Yes, you can use NSDate for alarm.

Comment: Look at the docs for NSDate and NSDateComponents.

Comment: If you need to associate the time with a specific date then you should use NSDate. If you just want a time without any regard to a date, then you can use an `int` representing the number of seconds or minutes since midnight. You really need to provide more details to give a good answer.

Comment: @rmaddy thanks. Yes, I don't need date(year, month, and day). I need only hour and minute part like 8:40. I want to alarm at 8:40 every day.